# Conditional expectation of random variable

Tags: probability, proof-verification, conditional-expectation

I have this home assignment in Introduction to Probability, and I'm not comfortable with definitions and heuristics. I really need someone to check if I'm even in the right direction.
The question: Ben chooses random numbers from 0,1,...,9 independently and with uniform probability, and arranges them in a sequence by the order of picking. What is the expectation of the amount of distinct numbers between the first two appearances of the number 0.
My way to start: define random variable $X$ for the amount of distinct numbers between first two appearances of 0. Define another random variable $Y$ that will return the number that's adjacent to the first $0$, now 
$$E[X]=E[E[X|Y]]=E[P(Y=0)E[x|Y=0]+P(Y\neq0)E[X|Y\neq0]]$$ since $Y=0 \implies X=0$ we got $E[X]=E[P(Y\neq0)E[X|Y\neq0]]=P(Y\neq0)E[X|Y\neq0]$, of course $P(Y\neq0)=\frac{9}{10}$, and starting counting from the index $Y$ as if we are "starting fresh" we get $E[X|Y\neq0]=E[X+1]$. So: $$\array{{E[X] = \frac{9}{10}E[X+1]}\\{\Downarrow}\\{E[X]=9}}$$ Which is kind of makes sense but I'm not sure at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am going to assume that you don't count $0$ as one of the distinct digits seen between the first and second $0$s in the sequence.  So for instance if the sequence is $3,5,3,3,0,7,3, 7,0$, I would say there were $X=2$ distinct digits between the first and second $0$s (namely $7$ and $3$).

With this interpretation, the expected number of distinct digits seen between the first two zeros should be $4.5$.

To see this, imagine that after seeing the first $0$, Ben keeps picking until he has seen every digit at least once (including a second $0$), and writes down the order in which distinct digits only appear after the first $0$.  For instance he might write down $3,5,4,8,0,9,7,1,2,6$ (he does not list repeats).  In the example just given, he would have $X=4$ since the four digits $3,5,4,8$ occurred between zeros.

The value of $X$ is completely determined by the position of $0$ on this revised list.  And $0$ has an equal chance of being in any of the ten positions of the revised list; and so there is a $\frac{1}{10}$ probability that $X$ takes on each of the values $0, 1,2,\dots,9$.

Comment: Oh!  A much more elegant solution.  Very nice.

Answer (score 1):

Edited:   (I missed the key point on the first reading: we're counting *distinct* digits.)

---

Ah!   Everything makes sense until you say "we are starting fresh."   That would be true if we were counting the number of non-zero digits until the next $0$, which would be a geometric distribution.   However, we wish to count the number of **distinct** non-zero digits, so we don't have a memoryless situation.

As you did, we begin by partitioning on the event that we encounter (or don't) no other digits before the next zero.

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf E(X) &= \mathsf P(X=0)\mathsf E(X\mid X=0) + \mathsf P(X>0)\mathsf E(X\mid X>0)
\\ &= 0+ \tfrac 9{10}\mathsf E(X\mid X>0)
\end{align}$$

However, *this* process is not memoryless, so $\mathsf E(X\mid X>0)\neq 1+\mathsf E(X)$ .   To evaluate this we need to partition on whether or not we encounter a second distinct digit before the next zero, given we've encountered one such.

The probability of *not* encountering another distinct digit (after the first) is the probability of encountering 0 or more of that first digit, then encountering the zero.  $$\mathsf P(X=1\mid X>0)=\tfrac 1{10}\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \big(\tfrac 1 {10}\big)^n\right) = \tfrac 1 9$$

Similarly the probability of *not* encountering a third distinct digit (given we've encountered two) is the probability of encountering 0 or more of those two digits, then encountering the zero.  $$\mathsf P(X=2\mid X\geq 2)=\tfrac 1{10}\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \big(\tfrac 2 {10}\big)^n\right) = \tfrac 1 8$$

And in general:$$\mathsf P(X=r\mid X\geq r)=\tfrac 1{10}\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \big(\tfrac r {10}\big)^n\right) = \tfrac 1 {10-r} \qquad \text{for }r < 10$$

So we have:

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf E(X\mid X\geq r) & = \mathsf P(X=r\mid X\geq r)\cdot\mathsf E(X\mid X=r)+\mathsf P(X>r\mid X\geq r)\cdot\mathsf E(X\mid X>r)
\\ & = \tfrac r{10-r}+\tfrac {9-r} {10-r}\mathsf E(X\mid X\geq r+1)
\end{align}
$$

Thus:
$$\begin{align}
\mathsf E(X) & = \tfrac 9{10}(
\tfrac 1{9}+\tfrac {8} {9} (
\tfrac 2{8}+\tfrac {7} {8} (
\tfrac 3{7}+\tfrac {6} {7} (
\tfrac 4{6}+\tfrac {5} {6} (
\tfrac 5{5}+\tfrac {4} {5} (
\tfrac 6{4}+\tfrac {3} {4} (
\tfrac 7{3}+\tfrac {2} {3} (
\tfrac 8{2}+\tfrac {1} {2} (
\tfrac 9{1}+\tfrac {0} {1} )))))))))
\\ ~ & = \tfrac 1{10}( 1+ (2+ (3+ (4+(5+(6+(7+ (8+ (9 )))))))))
\\ ~ & = \tfrac 9 2
\end{align}$$

---

What you were doing was counting failures before the next success (the occurrence of a `0`).   That is, you were treating it as dealing with a geometric distribution.

Partitioning on the first trial's result *is* one classic way of obtaining this.

Let $Y$ be the count of failures before the next success, where, on any arbitary trial, the probability of success is $p$; independent of any previous trial results (the process has no memory).   Then we have

$\begin{align}
\mathsf E(Y\mid Y>0) & = 1+\mathsf E(Y) \tag{memoryless}
\\[1ex]
 \mathsf P(Y>0) & = (1-p) \tag{failed first trial}
\\[1ex]
\mathsf E(Y\mid Y=0) & = 0 \tag{obviously}
\\[2ex]
\mathsf E(Y) & = \mathsf P(Y=0)\mathsf E(Y\mid Y=0)+\mathsf P(Y > 0)\mathsf E(Y\mid Y>0)
\\[1ex] & = 0 + (1-p)\cdot(1+\mathsf E(Y))
\\[2ex]
\therefore \mathsf E(Y) & = \frac{1-p}{p}
\end{align}$

Comment: Maybe I don't understand, it seems that in this answer you are addressing $X$ as the amount of digits between zeros, but who many of them are distinct?

Comment: @UriaMor  Ah, ha. I missed that keyword: **distinct**.  I've updated my answer.  Meanwhile, paw88789 has provided a much more elegant solution getting the same result.

Comment: Conditioning seems to only complicate things here. The interest of the exercise, if any, is to show that one can count things differently and that this simplifies hugely the computations (and explains the end result).